# Screen Rotation RuntimeError

Tags: android, runtime-error, screen-rotation

Hi Im have a probem with my application. It crashes when screen is rotated. Application is running but whenever i try to rotate the screen it crashes and this the error i get. Do you have idea how to fix this? Thanks

```
09-25 00:19:30.283: D/dalvikvm(2649): GC_CONCURRENT freed 494K, 21% free 3005K/3804K, paused 34ms+32ms, total 350ms
09-25 00:19:31.253: D/AndroidRuntime(2649): Shutting down VM
09-25 00:19:31.283: W/dalvikvm(2649): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
09-25 00:19:31.493: E/AndroidRuntime(2649): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-25 00:19:31.493: E/AndroidRuntime(2649): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.projectsoftware/com.projectsoftware.AlbumsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-25 00:19:31.493: E/AndroidRuntime(2649):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
09-25 00:19:31.493: E/AndroidRuntime(2649):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
09-25 00:19:31.493: E/AndroidRuntime(2649):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3692)
09-25 00:19:31.493: E/AndroidRuntime(2649):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-25 00:19:31.493: E/AndroidRuntime(2649):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1240)
09-25 00:19:31.493: E/AndroidRuntime(2649):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-25 00:19:31.493: E/AndroidRuntime(2649):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-25 00:19:31.493: E/AndroidRuntime(2649):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
09-25 00:19:31.493: E/AndroidRuntime(2649):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-25 00:19:31.493: E/AndroidRuntime(2649):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-25 00:19:31.493: E/AndroidRuntime(2649):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
09-25 00:19:31.493: E/AndroidRuntime(2649):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
09-25 00:19:31.493: E/AndroidRuntime(2649):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-25 00:19:31.493: E/AndroidRuntime(2649): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-25 00:19:31.493: E/AndroidRuntime(2649):     at com.projectsoftware.AlbumsActivity$1.onTextChanged(AlbumsActivity.java:76)
09-25 00:19:31.493: E/AndroidRuntime(2649):     at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7231)
09-25 00:19:31.493: E/AndroidRuntime(2649):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3699)
09-25 00:19:31.493: E/AndroidRuntime(2649):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3554)
09-25 00:19:31.493: E/AndroidRuntime(2649):     at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
09-25 00:19:31.493: E/AndroidRuntime(2649):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3529)
09-25 00:19:31.493: E/AndroidRuntime(2649):     at android.widget.TextView.onRestoreInstanceState(TextView.java:3429)
09-25 00:19:31.493: E/AndroidRuntime(2649):     at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:12093)
09-25 00:19:31.493: E/AndroidRuntime(2649):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2588)
09-25 00:19:31.493: E/AndroidRuntime(2649):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2588)
09-25 00:19:31.493: E/AndroidRuntime(2649):     at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:12071)
09-25 00:19:31.493: E/AndroidRuntime(2649):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.restoreHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:1634)
09-25 00:19:31.493: E/AndroidRuntime(2649):     at android.app.Activity.onRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:938)
09-25 00:19:31.493: E/AndroidRuntime(2649):     at android.app.ListActivity.onRestoreInstanceState(ListActivity.java:219)
09-25 00:19:31.493: E/AndroidRuntime(2649):     at android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:910)
09-25 00:19:31.493: E/AndroidRuntime(2649):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1131)
09-25 00:19:31.493: E/AndroidRuntime(2649):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2158)
09-25 00:19:31.493: E/AndroidRuntime(2649):     ... 12 more
09-25 00:19:39.853: I/Process(2649): Sending signal. PID: 2649 SIG: 9
```

Here is the code

```
@SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "ViewHolder" })
public class AlbumsActivity extends ListActivity {

    Button imgClick;
    EditText inputSearch;   


    JSONArray albums = null;            
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    SimpleAdapter adapter = null;   
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> albumsList;
    AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private static final String URL_ALBUMS = "http://api.androidhive.info/songs/albums.php";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_SONGS_COUNT = "songs_count";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_albums);

        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#ff6d9850")));
        getActionBar().setIcon(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));

        albumsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        AlbumsActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs.toString());  
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {}

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {}
    });

        new LoadAlbums().execute();

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_albums, null);
        imgClick = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.row_click_imageView1);

        imgClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    showPopupMenu(v);
            }
        }); 
    }

    public void toast(View v){
        showPopupMenu(v);
    }
    private void showPopupMenu(View v){
        PopupMenu pop = new PopupMenu(AlbumsActivity.this, v);
        pop.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu,pop.getMenu());

        pop.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem arg0) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

                String album_name = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.album_name)).getText().toString();
                i.putExtra("album_name", album_name);
                startActivity(i);
                return true;
            }
            });
        pop.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == 2){
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            String message = data.getStringExtra("Message");
            TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.layout.activity_main);
            text.setText(message);
            }
        }
    }

    class LoadAlbums extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AlbumsActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.show();
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            String json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL_ALBUMS, "GET", params);

            Log.d("Albums JSON: ", "> " + json);

            try {               
                albums = new JSONArray(json);

                if (albums != null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < albums.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = albums.getJSONObject(i);

                        String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        String songs_count = c.getString(TAG_SONGS_COUNT);

                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                        map.put(TAG_SONGS_COUNT, songs_count);

                        albumsList.add(map);
                    }
                }else{
                    Log.d("Albums: ", "null");
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    ListView lv = getListView();
                    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2, long arg3) {

                            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TrackListActivity.class);

                            String album_id = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.album_id)).getText().toString();
                            i.putExtra("album_id", album_id);               
                            startActivity(i);
                        }
                    });     

                    AlbumsActivity.this.adapter = new SimpleAdapter(AlbumsActivity.this, albumsList, R.layout.list_item_albums, new String[] { TAG_ID, TAG_NAME, TAG_SONGS_COUNT }, new int[] {R.id.album_id, R.id.album_name, R.id.songs_count });
                    setListAdapter(AlbumsActivity.this.adapter);

                    pDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Some code would be nice...

Comment: I edited my post. Please check and see the code. thanks

Comment: onTextChanged() method is called on Activity re-creation. Add check if `cs` is not null

Comment: @AlexanderZhak my cs is null. how do i make it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During runtime configuration change(like screen orientation change), by default android restarts the running activity so you should be able to handle this runtime configuration changes. Which is why you're getting NullPointerException because that Activity of yours restarts hence you need to manage initializing/retaining state of your objects there. Here's the official android guide which might help you addressing your problem http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Answer (score -1):

When the screen rotates, the `Activity` will be re-created, the `OnCreate()` method will be executed, and the `EditText`'s `OnTextChanged()` method will be called, but now `cs` is `null`.

To fix it, we can add the activity attributes:

```
"android: configChanges = "orientation | keyboardHidden"
```

When the screen rotates, it would not call the `onCreate()` method any more. 
At the same time, we overwrite the `onConfigurationChanged()` method to listen to screen orientation changes.

Comment: That's not a fix, that's a bandaid. You need to be able to handle the activity being recreated at any time.

Comment: Dude!  He correctly identified the problem!  Not only that he offered a really commonly used solution!  Yes, there are better solutions... So *GIVE* one!

Comment: It's not a solution, it's *hiding* the problem. You're still going to crash if you put your app to the background and android kills off your activity. Or if someone changes the locale. Or removes the sim card. Or any other configuration change.

Comment: @Jonathan Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14 android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"